# Regression of Y on X given only delta X

Tags: regression, linear

I am trying to do a very simple regression of $Y$ on $X$. However my data presents a constraint. I have $Y$ but for $X$, the data I have is only $\delta X$ - that is the change over years - I do not have the levels.

Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you not reconstruct X from delta X by integration (up to an additive constant)?

Comment: presumably he doesn't have the initial X value $X_0$ meaning that while he can integrate/sum, it wont give the full value.

Comment: @Patty which would affect the constant term but not the slope, so if the slope estimate was the main concern, that may not be a big issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Yes I am interested only in the slope estimate. And yes I did follow a variant of what is being suggested. I took $X_0$ as $0$ and then summed up to get the levels.